# Django REST framework many to many serializer

Tags: serialization, m2m, django-rest-framework

I got models:

```
class Car: 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, default='')


class Wheel:
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, default='')
    cars =  models.ManyToManyField(Car)
```

and serializers:

```
class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta: 
        model = Car
        fields = ('name')

class WheelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cars = CarSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Wheel
        fields = ('name', 'cars')
```

It's works fine with Wheel case, it's shows me wheels and cars inside them. But I want to call cars and see wheels inside Cars. It's possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to create new serializers:

```
class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta: 
         model = Car
         fields = ('name')

class WheelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Wheel
        fields = ('name', 'cars')



class CarWheelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        cars = CarSerializer(many=True, required=False)
        class Meta: 
            ....
```

and WheelCarSerializer same way.